# If a java pojo is declared as an object, how do you control jackson serialization based on the run time type?

Tags: java, spring, jackson

For example, if I declare a `Map<String,Object>` with a mixed type value set and I try to serialize with a custom `TypeResolverBuilder`, I don't have access to the run time type of the value.

But if I want to write type information for some of the values and not others, how can that be accomplished? I've been reading into the `DefaultSerializerProvider` and it seems to ignore the run time type and just use the JavaType (which is Object.class)

We're using Jackson 2.9

Answer (score 3):

If you are able to edit your POJOs where you need to control the output you should be able to extend `JsonSerializer` and only write the information you want in the output of the serialize method.

You could also be able to annotate your map to provide a custom serializer and interogate the object to be serialized using `instanceof`

```
@JsonSerialize(keyUsing = SpecialSerializer.class) 
Map<String, Object> map;
```

And then in your serializer:

```
 @Override
    public void serialize(Object value, 
      JsonGenerator gen,
      SerializerProvider serializers) 
      throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
           if(value instanceof MySpecialObject){

                 //special logic here
          }
    }
```